# Dynamic left join in Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I have something like following

```
if (this.IncludeGuestlist)
{
    return from tn in tnQuery
           join gi in bl.Database.GuestlistItems on tn.Id equals gi.TicketNumberId into gj
           from giJoined in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new TicketNumberTempDTO()
           {
               Id = tn.Id,
               LookupId = tn.LookupId,
               CheckingId = tn.CheckingId,
               GuestlistName = giJoined.GuestlistDefinition.Name
           };
}
else
{
    return from tn in tnQuery               
           select new TicketNumberTempDTO()
           {
               Id = tn.Id,
               LookupId = tn.LookupId,
               CheckingId = tn.CheckingId
           };
}
```

Given that I don't want the left join happening when not necessary, is it somehow possible to unify this so that I don't have to write the select twice?

[e.g. write the "base" select (Id, LookupId, CheckingId) and if IncludeGuestlist is true, add the join and GuestlistName to existing select]

EDIT:
Simplified model as following, tnQuery is a dynamically build IQueryable

```
public class TicketNumber
{     
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LookupId { get; set; }
    public string CheckingId { get; set; }
}

public class GuestlistItem
{     
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int GuestlistDefinitionId { get; set; }
    public virtual GuestlistDefinition GuestlistDefinition { get; set; }

    public int TicketNumberId { get; set; }
    public virtual TicketNumber TicketNumber { get; set; }
}

public class GuestlistDefinition
{     
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post you data model please? So we can write you a complete example based on your code.

Comment: I've added the simplified model

Comment: Do you have LazyLoading enabled?

Comment: No, I'd like to obtain the model in a single round-trip to the DB

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a new navigation property to TicketNumber :

```
public class TicketNumber
{     
    // your properties

    public virtual List<GuestlistItem> GuestListItems { get; set; }
}
```

And then :

```
var query = context.Set<TicketNumber>().AsQueryable();

if (IncludeGuestlist)
{
    query = query.Include(tn => tn.GuestListItems);
}

var ticketNumbers = query.Where(/* do your filter logic here */).ToList(); // You can use SingleOrDefault instead. It depends on your case.

return ticketNumbers
    .Select(tn => new TicketNumberTempDTO
    {
        // make your assignation logic
        GuestlistName = GuestListItems?.FirstOrDefault()?.Name
    }).ToList();
```

With this conditional include, you do the join only if necessary.

Note : I made some assumptions given your data model (what is the cardinality of your relationships?). Don't hesitate to precise some things so I can be more explicit.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. While this indeed works, my TicketNumber entity is way bigger [containing cca 30 properties]. What I wanted to achieve was the lowest possible database load [meaning not to load those 30 properties when not needed] and only make a select while keeping the select part clean

I had trouble with navigation properties that is mentioned in another question I opened, therefore I don't have the navigation property unfortunately. Still that wouldn't really help as the trouble here is the dynamic join with dynamic select. Just wanted to know if possible somehow

Comment: With these kind of information, I don't think what you want to achieve is possible. Having a conditional set is forbidden in LinqToEntities. Maybe you could use a StoredProcedure instead?